# SUM the max values over multiple groupings. DAX SSAS

Tags: scope, ssas, tabular, dax

Link to Table...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUVfc.png

I have a table with multiple repeated values associated with a certain group.  I'm trying to scope out the max for each group, then sum it.

Answer needs to be 50 + 25 + 10 + 70

I've tried various SUMX and can't seem to get the filter correct.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

```
My Measure := SUMX(VALUES(Table1[Group]),CALCULATE(MAX(Table1[Value])))
```

Comment: Hi @WhereEaglesDare if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Great answer! You saved the day!